# How to save objects with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

Hi am confused with how to save object with fluent nhibernate.

say I have a class Foo which has one to many relationship with ChildFoo.

Table foo has id and name. Table ChildFoo has sourceID which matches the id for the foo entity.

The mapping would look like this.

```
class Foo 
{
   public virtual ID {get;set;}
   public IList<FooChild> Components{get;set;}
}
```

the mapping would look like this

```
public FooMap : ClassMap<FooMap> 
{
   public FooMap()
   {
      HasMany(x => x.Components).KeyColumn("SourceID");
   }
}
```

Now when I want to save FooMap with some collection of Components, how do I tell fluent nhibernate to save the entity ( a class foo with a bunch of Foo Children stored in the Components list) I have created, without me requiring me to save each component manually.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to change your HasMany mapping to the following:

```
HasMany(x => x.Components).KeyColumn("SourceID").Inverse().Cascade.All();
```

Also it looks like your mapping is incorrect.  It should be this:

```
public FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> 
{
   public FooMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.ID, "SourceID");
      HasMany(x => x.Components)
         .KeyColumn("SourceID")
         .Inverse()
         .Cascade.All();
   }
}
```

Comment: are you sure I have to do Inverse() ? doesn't that have the oposite effect ? 

I was able to do as you say but without the Inverse() method call

Comment: For the behavior you want I think you do want this. No not exactly.  Please read this [article](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/9f24fdcc8ee520fe) for further detail on what Inverse does on a HasMany relationship.  The description is somewhat unclear on the Fluent Wiki.